# Active Directory custom attribute with lookup values

Tags: active-directory, custom-attributes, lookup-tables

We need to create a custom attribute in Active Directory that will contains lookup values and the user object will need to choose one or multiple values in this lookup. The lookup values will be defined in this custom attribute. Our application will be able to read this custom attribute.

User is related to a Campus.

- Campus 1
- Campus 2
- Campus 3

And just one campus can be selected. The list of campus is managed in the Active Directory.

How we can acheive this by extending the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really NOT do this. Extending the schema to store something like that is like using a nuclear bomb to open a packet of cheezeits.

Active Directory has plenty of attributes that never get used, in this case I suggest the location attribute (l), division or department.

Comment: Ok, but the department attribute is a string value. What we want is a lookup values of department and the user can only choose one of them. So how would you do this?

Comment: @sebascomeau Selecting from a list of options is a function of the UI not Active Directory. You can't have an option that allows selection from a list just using AD, even if you edit the schema.

Comment: So we need to have an application that have the lookups and attributes that will save the selected value(Id and/or Description), right?

Comment: @sebascomeau Correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own attribute changing the Active-Directory Schema, or using an existing attribute that is not exploited in your organization.

---

Edited

You can create your own class derivated from user, but for me, a Camppus is more an organizationalUnit (OU), and then link user to the nouw object using an attribute of with the  `unique-name` syntax in fact a DN which keep referencial integrity.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but you have not answered my question. Check my edited original question.

Comment: Sorry, but for me your question is not so clear. You want that an object attribut point to one Campus ?

Comment: Its simple... how could we create an object like user but it will be campus that will have Name as attribute. And the user will have a attribute that linked one campus.